# Normal matrix as sum of normal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If

$N_1$ and $N_2$ are normal matrices,
and they commute,

Then

$N=N_1+N_2$ is also normal.

Does the reverse implication hold?
it is if a normal matrix $N$ can be expressed as the sum of two normal matrices $N_1$ and $N_2$, is it true that these commute ?

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. The matrices$$N_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&2\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }N_2=\begin{bmatrix}2&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$$are normal and don't commute, but$$N_1+N_2=\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\4&3\end{bmatrix}$$is normal too.

Comment: +1: How did you come up with that example?

Comment: I picked two symmetric matrices. Automatically, both of them are normal and so is their sum. And since matrices seldom commute…

Comment: Yes, thanks, it was that simple. And it's always never granted to see the simple in any system or question.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.