# If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and skew-symmetric, respectively, and $A+B$ is normal, do $A$ and $B$ commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know that if $A$, $B$, and $A+B$ are normal matrices, it does not necessarily follow that $AB = BA$ (see [Normal matrix as sum of normal matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553112/normal-matrix-as-sum-of-normal-matrices)). But what if we know that $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is skew-symmetric? With this constraint added, does $A+B$ normal imply $AB=BA$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are real matrices, yes.  Let $C = A+B$.  We must have $C^T = A^T + B^T = A - B$, so $A = (C+C^T)/2$ and $B = (C - C^T)/2$.  But since $C$ is normal, $C$ and $C^T$ commute...

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!