# Simultaneous diagonalization of symmetric and skew-symmetric components of normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Take a real, normal matrix $A$. We know that $A = A_{sym} + A_{skew}$ for some symmetric matrix $A_{sym}$ and some skew-symmetrix matrix $A_{skew}$. It follows by an argument sketched [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642259/if-a-and-b-are-symmetric-and-skew-symmetric-respectively-and-ab-is-norm) that $A_{sym}$ and $A_{skew}$ commute. That seems to imply that they are simultaneously diagonalizable, i.e. have the same eigenvectors. As stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices):

> Two diagonalizable matrices $A$ and $B$ commute ($AB = BA$)  if they are simultaneously diagonalizable (that is, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that both $P^{-1}AP$ and $P^{−1}BP$ are diagonal). The converse is also true; that is, if two diagonalizable matrices commute, they are simultaneously diagonalizable

But how is this possible given that $A_{skew}$'s eigenvectors are complex and $A_{sym}$'s eigenvectors real?

Comment: Have you tried working through a $2 \times 2$ example?

Comment: Nonzero skew symmetric matrices are not diagonalisable over $\mathbb R$. They are diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I did but to be honest, I still don't get it. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental, but I can't put my finger on it

Comment: you may be thinking of (real orthogonal) simultaneous *block* diagonalization where $A_\text{skew}$ gets mapped to a skew symmetric matrix that has each block on the diagonal $2\times 2$ or $1\times 1$ and $A_\text{sym}\mapsto$ a matrix that has the same block structure, and is $\propto I$ on each.